# Regular Expression - is .*$ the same as .*

Tags: regex

I am cleaning up another person's regular expressions and they currently end all of theirs with

```
.*$
```

So wouldn't the following be exactly the same?

```
.*
```

Comment: Then they're identical, but I still wouldn't remove them in your clean-up.

Comment: Thank-you for the detailed explanation. I had not thought to consider the ramifications of 'multiline option' and 'dotall'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.*` will match as much as it can, but by default `.` doesn't match newlines. If the text you're matching against has newlines and you're in MULTILINE but *not* DOTALL mode, then `.*$` might not match where `.*` does. Without newlines (or if you're not in MULTILINE) or if you've set DOTALL, they're identical since `*` is a greedy operator and will match as much as it can.

In the end though, the exact answer depends on the regular expression engine. So your results may differ.

Comment: Paul says that if multiline is enabled they may behave differently. You say that if NOT in multiline then may behave differently. Am I reading this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

`$` asserts that the match reaches the end of the string, which will always happen since `.` matches anything. So, yes, they are the same.

However, as Paul Creasey pointed out, there are times when they aren't the same. When multiline is enabled, `$` will match the end of the multi-line string. But, unless dot-all (meaning "dot" matches all) is also enabled, `.` can't match newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Not always, it depends on the settings that are being used, most regex engines have a "multiline" mode, if that is enabled, they will behave differently.